# not getting the desired result

Tags: math, c++14

I has written the following code for fast exponential in coding Ninza I do not got the correct answer. My calculation part is correct, till calculating the exponent but I am unable to calculate the answer in desired modulo. Can anyone help how can I solve this issue?

```
int modularExponentiation(int x, int n, int m) {
int res=1;
    int t=n/2;
    while(t--){
        res=((res)%m)*((x)%m);
    }
    res=((res)%m)*((res)%m);
    if(n&1){
        res=(res*x)%m;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Let's assume n is even. The final operation is `res=((res)%m)*((res)%m);` which has a result in the range `0..m^2` and which you then return. Quick fix: add modulo to the final return `return res%m;`

Comment: In general you should apply modulo **after** each operation.